# DragonFlyBSD 6.4 can not get guest to work

Tags: dragonflybsd

I have installed DragonFly 6.4 on virtualbox 7.0.8 under Ubuntu
but have been unable to the the guest additions to work.

I added pkg's Xorg and slim.

It complains about "no screens found" and
"unable to connect to X server".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.